# How to find out why my DLL has grown so much

Tags: c++, optimization, profiler

A DLL I've been working on has recently grown a lot in size. Are there any tools that will tell my what is responsible for this? For instance, is it a template that is being instantiated too many times, or perhaps a 3rd party lib, or maybe boost?

I'm looking for a kind of profiler that looks at size rather than performance.

Comment: Well, you are the guy building it! Why do you need a profiler to see what you yourself must have added?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I'm trying to see if there's a particularly heavy class, template, or a function that's being inlined too aggressively -- I don't know how to figure that stuff out by inspection.

Comment: What have you been feeding it? Didn't they tell you no pizza after midnight in the shop?

Comment: Easy. Go back in your version control to when you were happy with the size. Diff then with now.

Answer (score 7):

Are you talking about size of the DLL in bytes?  Try using the dumpbin utility.  This can show you what's inside your DLL.  /ARCHIVEMEMBERS should show you the individual object modules.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429

Comment: ++ Yeah. I either do that, or get a mapfile and see what's in there. Likely as not, it's filled with big chunks of class library put in there because of some variable I declared, that I didn't actually even need.

Answer (score 3):

If your DLL has other dependencies and you are using STATIC linking to link your DLL to them, you can expect your DLL to grow larger:

[Static linking vs dynamic linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking/1993407#1993407)

> - **Static** linking can make binaries easier to distribute to diverse user environments (at the cost of sending a large and more resource hungry program).

**EDIT:**

I found the answers in this thread quite interesting for your problem: [Profiling DLL/LIB Bloat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1598703/176769)

But an interesting experiment would be to verify if for each template instantiation, the resulting executable size grows linearly. If it does, you know your problem is template instantiation. There's a [decent article here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/RefactoringTemplateBloat.aspx?q=c%2b%2b%20template%20code%20bloat) that talks about this type of problem and presents a technique to refactor it.

**EDIT:**

There's a big chance that your problem is a consequence of using boost headers. Check this thread to find out why: [Why does using boost increase file size so much?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2121889/176769)

Comment: Unfortunately, distribution to "diverse user environments" is precisely what I have to do. Switching to dynamic linking was my first thought, but that was immediately ruled out for a number of reasons.

Comment: @karlphilip I'm using the header-only parts of boost.

Comment: @Pedro An interesting experiment would be to verify if for each template instantiation, the resulting executable size grows linearly.

Comment: There's a decent page on The Code Project called *Refactoring Template Bloat*, it might be interesting for you to read if you detect that the problem is really templates instantiation: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/RefactoringTemplateBloat.aspx?q=c%2b%2b+template+code+bloat